# DonutOutputCache is not clearing cache when using variable

Tags: asp.net-mvc, caching, asp.net-caching, asp.net-cache

I have an ActionResult which i want it to be cached based on the id

```
[DonutOutputCache(Duration = 3600, VaryByParam = "product_Id")]
public ActionResult ProductInfo(Guid product_Id)
{
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
    return PartialView(_repository.GetProductInfo(product_Id));
}
```

It is working good.

When i want to remove the cache, i use this syntax

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult SaveDetails(DetailsModel model)
{
    try
    {
        // save action here, then remove cache

        var cacheManager = new OutputCacheManager();
        cacheManager.RemoveItem("Common", "ProductInfo", new { product_Id = model.Product_Id });

        return Json(new { hasError = false }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return Json(new { hasError = true, message = ex.Message }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

OutputCacheManager().RemoveItem doesn't work when i specify a parameter.

It works if i just use

```
cacheManager.RemoveItem("Common", "ProductInfo");
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution

it seems that the parameter can't contain uppercase letters. This is a known bug which will be fixed.

Change product_Id to product_id and it will work.

Comment: Nice, I'm wonderying why you don't have more point for this question. On my side, I faced another issue; the problem occurs when you specify VaryByParam="*" and you have parameters with camel case. In this case, I must specify each parameter separated by semi-colon or set all my parameters with lower case. Do you have an idea about this problem?

Comment: I think you have to name all the parameters without camel case. That post from asp.net forums was created by me also:) i was really trying to find out a solution for that problem and seems that nobody faced it (until now)